# Where can I find iPad Sample Code

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I know the iPhone has a site with sample apps and code for the iPhone.  Are there any resources out there for the iPad?

I would like iPad specific examples like using split view, etc.

Comment: +1 to counter the unjustified down vote. What's wrong with this question? To whoever down voted, why not consider adding a comment to explain how the question could be improved!

Comment: I am still looking for "big" ipad sample projects... Anyone with a tip?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're a member of the Apple Developer Connection who's paid for the $99/year iPhone developer license, the [iPhone Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action) has everything you need for iPad support, including:

- [iPad Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/index.html)
- [iPad Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadHIG/index.html)
- [Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/navigation/index.html#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code)

When you get to the iPhone Dev Center, click "iPhone SDK 3.2 beta."

Comment: You don't need to be a paying member for this. Just register as a free member and you get access to all the developer material (XCode, docs, sample code, etc.)

Comment: @Niels: True, though I think when this was posted you did for the beta.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the 3 links you provided has everything **except** for sample code. I can not find one single ipad app on the apple dev site.

Answer (score 22):

My BSD-licensed open source application [Molecules](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/molecules) has been [updated with an iPad interface](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2010/04/03/molecules-version-14-now-ipad) to make it a universal iPhone / iPad application, and the code for that is available for you to peruse.  It uses a UISplitViewController to define its primary iPad interface, with UIPopoverControllers for additional toolbar actions.

Comment: +1 because I just used Molecules a few days ago to help me create a universal app.

Answer (score 8):

**iPad sample code**

[iPad Programming Tutorial – Hello World++](http://icodeblog.com/2010/04/05/ipad-programming-tutorial-hello-world/)

Comment: link=> http://doronkatz.com/ipad-programming-tutorial-hello-world

Comment: lets give credit to the original author: http://icodeblog.com/2010/04/05/ipad-programming-tutorial-hello-world/

Answer (score 6):

We just released the source code to our game, Tap Blaster HD. It's fairly simple, but seen quite a few downloads on the App Store. Could be a nice project to learn a bit from.

Here's a link, hope you find it useful.
http://9magnets.com/project-tapblaster.html

Answer (score 5):

There is a [list](http://iphoneos-developer.blogspot.com/2010/05/ipad-sample-code.html) of Apples iPad code samples at http://iphoneos-developer.blogspot.com/2010/05/ipad-sample-code.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can find real ipad sample for now... There is no sample Apps with "**split view controler"** or the "**Popover**" component" like they recommand in the Guideline for iPad

Nb. : In xCode, you can start a new project with "Split View-based Application" template, this is a minimalistic implementation of the Ipad split view.

Answer (score 1):

iPad runs the iPhone OS, so iPhone sample apps are iPad sample apps.

Comment: apps are built different for the iPad. though they use similar views and form objects the actual layout is plain different.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Xcode > Help > Developer Documentation to search for sample apps.

Answer (score 1):

check the source code for iPad Split view Controller Tutorial at the following link.[iPad Split View Navigation Controller Sample code](http://rapidshare.com/files/378504579/iPadSplitView_20100421_1053_.zip)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad) is an improved splitview controller, MGSplitViewController from Matt Gemmell.

Answer (score 1):

Few days ago I found a really nice book for iPad programming :

iPad Programming: A Quick-Start Guide for iPhone Developers

I took it as eBook, there are some really interesting advanced samples that will help you to create reach human experience application.

Moreover, you can download all sample code explain on the book.

For more information go here : http://pragprog.com/titles/sfipad/ipad-programming

Unfortunately, this eBook is not free...

Answer (score 0):

The Molecules sample code is a great sample because it covers writing a single app that works on both ipad and iphone interfaces, and uses ipad split view controller.

Answer (score 0):

you would google for Open sourced "iPad apps" or "universal apps". you will find some nice apps like wikihow, wordpress, molecules..etc.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

I have found lots of great iPhone & iPad code on http://www.github.com 
Lots of nice reusable libraries too like AFNetworking, NSLogger, and more.