# Open source iPad applications

Tags: open-source, ipad

Are there any open source iPad applications ? Please help me by giving some sample ipad source code  links , which will help to design good iPad applications..

Comment: http://github.com/rackspace/ipad-rackspacecloud

Comment: http://github.com/duivesteyn-net/iPad-Empty-Project---6-View-Controllers-on-the-Left

Comment: http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2010/06/24/ipad-programming-roundup/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find iPad Sample Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276513/where-can-i-find-ipad-sample-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me open source is the opposite of Apple...

Anyways, any Iphone application can also work on the Ipad there are obviously differences on what you should do with each. I think what your looking for are tutorials

Some websites I found:
http://maniacdev.com/
http://www.developforipad.com/
http://www.9to5mac.com/translate?url=ipad-video-tutorials-324698362
http://www.ipadtutorialvideos.com/category/ipad-tutorials/ipad-development
http://iphonedevelopmentbits.com/

Answer (score 1):

Some tutorials I had good luck with:

http://iphonedeveloperzone.com

http://mobijournal.com