# Do you know some good (to learn from) iOS open source apps?

Tags: ios, open-source

Today I read abouts this on *hacker news* https://github.com/udibr/bitcoinApp which is an interesting app, and is a good resource to learn from.

Do you know about some other open source iOS apps from where I can enrich my iOS/objective-c knowledge?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any Open-source iPhone applications around?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200850/are-there-any-open-source-iphone-applications-around)

Comment: See also [Where can I find iPad Sample Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276513/where-can-i-find-ipad-sample-code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a game programmer perspective (mine)...

You can check [cocos2d engine](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone).

[Oolong Engine](http://code.google.com/p/oolongengine) (for 3D OpenGL ES).

Also, [Canabalt](https://github.com/ericjohnson/canabalt-ios) went open source.

Comment: WordPress for iOS, too: http://ios.trac.wordpress.org/browser